# Add MPMoviewPlayerController to UIViewController for fullscreen playback rotation

Tags: ios, uiview

I have the same question with :
[MPMoviewPlayerController fullscreen playback rotation with underlying UIViewController with portrait mode only (rotation disallowed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014176/mpmoviewplayercontroller-fullscreen-playback-rotation-with-underlying-uiviewcont?rq=1)

and I think the answer of this question is very useful. Then I add a UIViewController for this purpose.
First: youtubePlayer is a MPMoviePlayerController, the under code send youTubeView's frame to youtubePlayer and show youtubePlayer on youTubeView:

```
[youtubePlayer.view setFrame:youTubeView.bounds];
[youTubeView addSubview:youtubePlayer.view];
```

After switch to FullScreen, I want to add youtubePlayer.view to a new UIViewController, then it can auto-rotation:
    playerFullScreen = [[UIViewController alloc]init];

```
[playerFullScreen.view addSubview:youtubePlayer.view];
[nav pushViewController:playerFullScreen animated:NO];
```

but the screen turn white, video not show up, what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `UIViewController`; `MPMoviePlayerViewController` works just as fine, and it has its own functions to present videos modally, just like YouTube (I think). Also instead of `addSubview`, try using `setView`:

I spent a long time researching this and the following works perfectly.

```
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

//Calls for movie playback once video is finished
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];
playerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]init];
[moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
[playerView setView:moviePlayer.view];

[moviePlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerView];

[moviePlayer play];
NSLog(@"playing video view");
```

and when dismissing its calls

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self      
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:player];

    [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];

    NSLog(@"removed video view");
}
```