# iOS - Allow Landscape mode on videos only

Tags: ios, video, landscape-portrait

I have videos throughout my app. Some using MPMoviePlayerController, others in a UIWebView with YouTube. I want my app to be totally portrait. However, I want to give the user the option to flip to landscape when there's a video (not force, but optional).

I've been searching the web for an answer, but I haven't found anything yet.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: if your app is landscape then just do: [mp shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:NO];

Comment: see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14802980/542400

Comment: are you using rootViewController in your app?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and fixed it by adding this in my app delegate, basically allowing Landscape orientation only on subclasses of MPMoviePlayerViewController:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@implementation UIViewController (orientationFix)

-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[self class] isSubclassOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    if ([[self class] isSubclassOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

@end

@implementation MyAppDelegate
.
.
.
@end
```

Comment: In my case, I use YTPlayerView inside a normal View Controller so this method won't work, because it will allow the whole view controller to be landscaped, instead of only when the video is playing.

Comment: @VanDuTran hi! Did you find a solution for that please? I'm also using YTPlayerView. And also did the YTPlayer sound works for you in a real device?

Answer (score 0):

either subclass it and -

(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
   //return landscape here
}
for ios6:
shouldAutorotate return no

or

use this:

[MPMoviewPlayerController fullscreen playback rotation with underlying UIViewController with portrait mode only (rotation disallowed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014176/mpmoviewplayercontroller-fullscreen-playback-rotation-with-underlying-uiviewcont)

Answer (score 0):

**Add These Lines in AppDelegate.**

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
        return NO; 
    }

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //LandScapeMode:- UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    //PortraitMode:- 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait 
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    //LandScapeMode:- UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
   // ProtraitMode:-
   return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this in app delegate.**

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
        return NO; 
    }

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //LandScapeMode:- UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    //PortraitMode:- 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait 
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    //LandScapeMode:- UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
   // ProtraitMode:-
   return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theurl];
self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
self.moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(self.moviePlayer.view.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2));
UIWindow *backgroundWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:backgroundWindow.frame];
[backgroundWindow addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
[self.moviePlayer play];
```