# MPMoviePlayerViewController to support Landscape Video

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an app I building and well, Im a little stuck, its a pretty basic app, its locked to Portrait only and contains a UINavigationController, however, I want to add fullscreen video so I am using MPMoviePlayer in one of the views. My question is, how do I give the video the ability to play in landscape while the rest of the app remains in portrait? The Rotate methods do not seem to be getting called in my views, I am assuming that this has something to do with the NavigationController.

Comment: Issue seems to be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960665/mpmovieplayercontroller-re-orientation-portrait-to-landscape-and-back-to-portrai